Github Projects: How to auto convert all project items to an issue in a specific repository?
I create a GitHub project to track development work my team is doing in a repository.
The scope of the project supposed to be a specific repository.
Currently, all project items I create remain in Draft mode until I convert them to an issue in a specific Repository. After creating many project items I found converting them to an issue in specific repository redundant, inefficient and annoying.
Is there any way to make the scope of a project a specific repository, so that I don't have to convert project items one at a time?
In essence I need to automate this or assign default values to it.

